# ConTeXt: Change some footnote symbols from numbers to asterisk, dagger, etc

Tags: footnotes, context

Is it possible to change the footnote symbols from numbers to asterisk, dagger, etc. in the 2nd and 5th footnotes in the MWE below? In other words, is it possible to use non-number footnote symbols for specific footnotes?

```
\setuplayout [height=10cm]
\startdocument
    First sentence.\footnote{This is a footnote given with the number 1.}
    Second sentence.\footnote{This footnote should be given with an asterisk, but it isn't.}  
    Third sentence.\footnote{This footnote should be given with the number 2, but it isn't.}
    Fourth sentence.\footnote{This footnote should be given with the number 3, but it isn't.}
    Fifth sentece.\footnote{This footnote should be given with a dagger, but it isn't.}
\stopdocument
```

Comment: I think you are aware of `\setupnotation[footnote][way=bypage,numberconversion=set 2]`. I don't know how to mix those two kinds of notations, which is something non structural.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of \setupnotation[footnote][way=bypage,numberconversion=set 2], but I do not know how to mix them.

Comment: You will have to define an own numberconversion.

Comment: This is [Asterix](https://images.app.goo.gl/uJGzPXSB3UvEGkBy6), * is an asterisk. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question in ConTeXt mailing list (https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) and Hans Hagen answered it swiftly :) Here is the answer I got with slight modifications:

```
\setupindenting
   [yes,small]

\defineconversion
   [mymix]
   [a,b,c]

\definenotation
   [symfootnote]
   [footnote]
   [counter=]

\setupnotation
   [footnote]
   [align={hz,hanging},
    indenting={yes,small,next}]

\setupnotation
   [symfootnote]
   [align={hz,hanging},
    indenting={yes,small,next},
    numberconversion=mymix,
    way=bypage]

\startdocument
    This is the first sentence with a footnote.\footnote{This is the first footnote and its mark is "1".}
    This is the second sentence with a footnote.\symfootnote{This is the second footnote and its mark is "a". }
    This is the third sentence with a footnote.\footnote{This is the third footnote and its mark is "2". }
    This is the fourth sentence with a footnote.\footnote{This is the fourth footnote and its mark is "3". }
    This is the fifth sentence with a footnote.\symfootnote{This is the fifth footnote and its mark is "b". }
\stopdocument
```

Instead of defining a custom conversion ("mymix" in the example above), we can also use the predefined conversion "set 2", which gives us asterisk, dagger, etc. like so:

```
\setupindenting
   [yes,small]

\definenotation
   [symfootnote]
   [footnote]
   [counter=]

\setupnotation
   [footnote]
   [align={hz,hanging},
    indenting={yes,small,next}]

\setupnotation
   [symfootnote]
   [align={hz,hanging},
    indenting={yes,small,next},
    numberconversion=set 2,
    way=bypage]

\startdocument
  This is the first sentence with a footnote.\footnote{This is the  first footnote and its mark is "1".}
  This is the second sentence with a footnote.\symfootnote{This is  the second footnote and its mark is "∗". }
  This is the third sentence with a footnote.\footnote{This is the  third footnote and its mark is "2". }
  This is the fourth sentence with a footnote.\footnote{This is the fourth footnote and its mark is "3". }
  This is the fifth sentence with a footnote.\symfootnote{This is the fifth footnote and its mark is "†". }
\stopdocument
```

Hope it helps.